# Very simple perl script has massive memory leak

Tags: linux, perl, rhel

I'm using a perl script to transform a file and found just reading from stdin and writing to stdout is enough to cause a massive memory leak. It gets up to around 20gig and I presume gets killed by the OS. Here's a script that shows the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
foreach my $line(<STDIN>)
{
  print $line;
}
```

And I'm running it like this

```
cat inputFile.x | perl test.pl > outputFile.x
```

As soon as I run this memory heads upwards at about 0.5gig per second. The input file is 68gig so it looks like perl is never releasing memory. I've tried all sorts of stuff like undef $line, using a ref, defining $line outside the foreach. Is there a way to force perl to release the memory?

EDIT: Note, running on Red Hat 6.5 64 bit, Perl 5.10.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `foreach` will load an entire filehandle into memory before iterating on it.

Instead, to iterate on a file line by line, always use a `while` loop.

In this instance, I would recommend just letting perl `open` the file itself.  You do this by simply passing the filename as a parameter to the script and iterating on `<>`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <>) {
    print $line;
}
```

And invoke the script like so:

```
perl test.pl inputFile.x > outputFile.x
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, +1 for mentioning why the foreach is a problem. In my case I can't open the file directly as this script is part of a Hadoop system that streams the data via stdout

Answer (score 6):

Use a `while` loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
  print $line;
}
```

Also, you don't need to push data through the pipe. You can open a file handle and let `perl` read through it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'my_big_file.txt' or die $!;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  print $line;
}
```